# nginx location proxy shows not found

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a VPS and NGINX on it and I am trying run a flask app and I want address of flask app be something like `site.com/flask` but location doesnt work for that, it only runs main Address `site.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/cert.pem ;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/privkey.pem ;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/chain.pem ;
    server_name bot.itarashe.zone www.bot.itarashe.zone ;

    location = ~^/flask/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/saeb/py/flask/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
    location / {}
}
```

but if I remove `~^/flask`

it works in main address

```
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/cert.pem ;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/privkey.pem ;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot.itarashe.zone/chain.pem ;
    server_name bot.itarashe.zone www.bot.itarashe.zone ;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/saeb/py/flask/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

}
```

I tried

```
location /flask {}
location /flask/ {}
location ~^/flask {}
location = ...
```

none of them didnt work,
access log is:

```
104.244.78.207 - - [27/Sep/2018:01:50:13 -0400] "GET /flask/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

and error log shows no error:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
[sudo] password for saeb: 
2018/09/27 00:15:50 [error] 2650#2650: *13 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.175.74.27, server: bot.itarashe.zone, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "bot.itarashe.zone"
2018/09/27 00:27:23 [error] 2650#2650: *16 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249.66.76, server: bot.itarashe.zone, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "oldflight.ir"
2018/09/27 00:27:23 [error] 2650#2650: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/font/IranSans/IRANSans-Medium-web.woff2" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249.66.75, server: bot.itarashe.zone, request: "GET /assets/font/IranSans/IRANSans-Medium-web.woff2 HTTP/1.1", host: "oldflight.ir"
2018/09/27 01:09:02 [notice] 2811#2811: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:27:45 [notice] 2831#2831: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:42:01 [notice] 2876#2876: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:42:41 [notice] 2889#2889: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:43:54 [notice] 2902#2902: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:44:38 [notice] 2915#2915: signal process started
2018/09/27 01:50:06 [notice] 2936#2936: signal process started
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my problem solved, Nginx did what it needs to do, it calls socket but with `/flask`
and I didnt define `@app.route('/flask')`